# Passing user and password to a redirected page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect the user from a web page to another one that is password protected. Because the user comes on the first page scanning a barcode using a specific terminal (think to it as a smartphone with a tailored barcode reader application that adds a couple of data (user and password) to its output).

Example: the user scans the barcode pointing to https://www.acme.com/redir.html, the application adds user and password and redirects the user to the right page: https://bob:redpaRrot93@www.acme.com/redir.html

what I want is transfer bob and redpRrot93 to the page where redir redirects so for example: https://bob:redpaRrot93@zeta.com/pages/destination.html

Actually I tested this code and I now it works:

```
<script>
    function redirectToContent(){
            if (location.protocol == "https:"){
                window.location='https\x3A\x2F\x2Fspock:vorreivolare53@www.micron-engineering.gq/ppages/404.html';
            }
            else {
                window.location='http\x3A\x2F\x2Fspock:vorreivolare53@www.micron-engineering.gq/ppages/404.html';
            }
    }
</script>
```

but I did not find a simple way to pass user and password from the redir page.

This is the updated (working) code:

```
<script>
    function redirectToContent(){
            let username = "spock";
            let password = "vorreivolare53";
            // try using template string with backticks ``
            // window.location = `https://mywebsite/${username}/${password}`;               
            if (location.protocol == "https:"){
                window.location=`https\x3A\x2F\x2F${username}:${password}@www.micron-engineering.gq/ppages/404.html`;
            }
            else {
                window.location=`http\x3A\x2F\x2F${username}:${password}@www.micron-engineering.gq/ppages/404.html`;
            }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not only you're sending username and password in plain text, you're also supporting plain http to do it. My suggestion: don't do that. Ever. You should build a post request at the very least. Better would be to get an authentication token and pass that to the page. Also, if you plan to have any sort of banner on the pages (like google ads, or something), they might very well read the URL and you'd be leaking passwords all over the place.

Comment: At the end I will remove supporting http is just for testing, also data will be not in cliear, iti s just for the example. The client does not require a strong protection level, he asked to have maximum simplicity.

Comment: Actually I protected a folder using htpasswd file as normally done by web providers on Linux servers and obviously the password is encrypted but is also true that is possible to send user and password in plain text in this situation so it is mandatory to use only https as protocol. But at the moment, I am testing it on a website supporting http (just for testing).

Comment: Here's another suggestion: remove username and password completely. That's "maximum simplicity". But if you want to keep them, you need to do it the proper way. Also, please remove username, password AND the name of the website from the question.

Comment: Don't worry it is just a test web site with test data. At the end of the tests nothing will remain in that site. I am not stupid.

Comment: And using https, sending user nad password in plain text is done in the coorect way if you protect a folder using htpasswd file. Considering that my app stores the password locally and encrypted and that only before sending it has to decript and merge with the url of redirect.html it is not so bad... I am not protecting a bank...

Answer (score 0):

```
let username = "someUserName";
let password = "somePassword";

// try using template string with backticks ``
window.location = `https://mywebsite/${username}/${password}`;

/* 
This is the es6 JavaScript sintax which makes it A LOT easier to write strings containing variable values.
P.S. Notice that template string is writen with backtics (on keyboard it is located left of key 1), and not a single quotes ''
*/
```

Read more at: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: OK, it works perfectly. I updated my original post with the updated code following your solution.

Now I need to protect the redirect page considering it embeds user and password and that seems I have to put in plain text.

Comment: Now I need to protect the redirect page that embeds user and password in plain text.

So I could protect the folder of the redir.html file in the same way with a different user / password. Considering that the redir.html is on a folder not related with the website and that will be accessed using an Android app (that embeds user/password) and that at the end of the tests https wil be mandatory I think it may be sufficient for my client application.
Now I need to protect the redirect page considering it embeds user and password and that seems I have to put in plain text.